# How can I change the material of an object through a script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a script in unity where if you hit a button the door opens and the light above the door turns green signifying that the door is now open, so how can I change the material/color of that light through a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Changing material of the object:

```cs
someObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = customMaterial;
```

#### Changing color of the object:

```cs
Color someColor = new Color(0.5f, 0.4f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
someObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", someColor);
```